# Cant make field not nulleable on migration rollback

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

I have this migration.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->change();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable(false)->change();
    });
}
```

It makes the category_id field nullable on up method and work fine but when I try to rollback it returns this error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'category_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'products_category_id_foreign'
```

What should I do on rollback? The purpose of this migration is to make the field nullable when ran and make it back not nulleable on rollback.

Comment: The problem is that when you roll it back, every row that contains a null category_id suddenly becomes invalid. So you need to first remove those rows in order to run it. (And it might not work even then because it's a foreign key constraint - but it's worth trying.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try turning off foreign key constraints. Keep in mind the implications of this though.